# A file renamer in Perl that gets rid of spaces, commas, dots, and dashes

Tags: perl

I often find myself working with files I get from other users that mostly work on Windows machines (I, myself, am on a macOS) and they tend to name their files in all sorts of (weird & difficult to handle) ways.

For example, the files I get may contain any or all of the following:

- a space
- a dash
- a comma
- one or more dots, not counting the extension dot.

So, I might get these files:

- `This is a file example, 2nd edition.pdf`
- `Another.File.Name.I.Get.To.Work.With.pdf`
- `this-file-is-actually-named-this-way, 7th edition.pdf`

Having said the above, to make my life easier, I've learned some Perl (heard it's great at string handling) and wrote myself a program that takes a `directory` as an argument and renames all files within it.

By default, I use the `_` as the `replace_character` and `.pdf` as the file extension, as these are the types of files I mostly work with.

Can anyone of you, kind Perl mongers, review the code in terms of **readability**, **ease of maintenance**, and **usability**?

I am aware of TIMTOWTDI (*There’s more than one way to do it!*), but, as I've mentioned, I've just started learning Perl and would like to get a (sort of) *canonical* answer that focuses on writing clean, maintainable Perl, not a throw-away program.

I'm on this `Perl`:

```
This is perl 5, version 36, subversion 1 (v5.36.1) built for darwin-thread-multi-2level
```

And here's my code:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;
use File::Find;
use File::Copy;
use version; our $VERSION = qv('1.0.0');

=begin comment
Function sanitize_file_name sanitizes the file name by removing spaces, commas, dashes and dots
except the dot before the file extension.
=end comment

=cut
sub sanitize_file_name {
    my ($file_name, $replace_char) = @_;

    # Remove spaces
    $file_name =~ s/\s+/$replace_char/g;

    # Remove commas and dashes
    $file_name =~ s/[,-]+/$replace_char/g;

    # Replace consecutive underscores with a single underscore
    $file_name =~ s/(?<!\.)_+/$replace_char/g;

    # Replace dots with underscores, except the one before the file extension
    $file_name =~ s/(?<=\b)(?<!\.)\.(?![^.]+$)/$replace_char/g;

    return $file_name;
}


# Function to get the file name from a path
sub get_file_name {
    my ($file) = @_;
    my @path = split /\//, $file;
    return $path[-1];
}

# Function to rename the file
sub rename_file {
    my ($old_name, $new_name) = @_;
    my $old_file_name = get_file_name($old_name);
    my $new_file_name = get_file_name($new_name);

    if ($old_file_name ne $new_file_name) {
        rename $old_name, $new_name;
        print "File renamed: '$old_file_name' -> '$new_file_name'\n";
    }
}

# Function to process files in a directory
sub process_files {
    my ($file, $extension, $replace_char) = @_;

    return unless -f $file;
    return unless $file =~ /\.(?:$extension)$/i;

    my $new_file_name = sanitize_file_name($file, $replace_char);
    my $new_full_path = $file;
    $new_full_path =~ s/([^\/]+)$/$new_file_name/;
    rename_file($file, $new_full_path);
}

my $replace_char = '_'; # Default replacement character
my $extension = 'pdf';  # Default file extension
my $help;

# Parse command line options
GetOptions(
    'replace=s' => \$replace_char,
'ext=s' => \$extension,
    'help' => \$help
) or die 'Error in command line arguments\n';

# Display help message
if (defined $help) {
    print "Usage: $0 [options] DIRECTORY\n" or croak $!;
    print "Options:\n";
    print "  --replace=CHAR     Replace spaces with specified CHAR (default: underscore)\n";
    print "  --ext=EXTENSION    Process files with specified EXTENSION (default: pdf)\n";
    print "  --help             Display this help message\n";
    exit;
}

# Check if a directory is provided
if (@ARGV != 1) {
    print "Error: No directory provided\n";
    die "Usage: $0 [options] DIRECTORY\n";
}

my $directory = $ARGV[0];

# Check if the directory exists
if (-d $directory) {
    find(sub { process_files($File::Find::name, $extension, $replace_char) }, $directory);
} else {
    die "Error: Directory '$directory' not found\n";
}
```

Comment: Check whether rename fails, or use autodie, and use something like https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny#basename to extract basename.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have done an excellent job of using good coding style: good layout, good use of subroutines and good leveraging of other's code (modules).  It is great that you used `strict` and `warnings`.

Here are some improvements you can make.

Remove the unused `File::Copy` module.

There is no need to call `croak` in this line:

```
print "Usage: $0 [options] DIRECTORY\n" or croak $!;
```

The `print` will likely never fail, and even if it did, you want to execute the remaining `print` lines.  Also, `croak` is not a built-in function; it is from the `Carp` module, which you did not `use`.

Consider using the [Pod::Usage](https://perldoc.perl.org/Pod::Usage) module and POD code instead of the help statements you have.  This gives you a Unix-style manpage for free when you use the [perldoc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldoc) command.  For example, you can add this POD at the end of your code:

```
=head1 SYNOPSIS

renamer [options] DIRECTORY

    Options:
    --replace=CHAR     Replace spaces with specified CHAR (default: underscore)
    --ext=EXTENSION    Process files with specified EXTENSION (default: pdf)
    --help             Display this help message

=head1 DESCRIPTION

A file renamer that gets rid of spaces, commas, dots, and dashes.

=cut
```

Then you can run this command on your command line to get the manpage (assuming you named the Perl file `renamer`):

```
perldoc renamer
```

I ran [podchecker](https://perldoc.perl.org/podchecker) on your code, and it complained about your `=begin` POD.  I added line breaks to fix the errors:

```
=begin comment

Function sanitize_file_name sanitizes the file name by removing spaces, commas, dashes and dots
except the dot before the file extension.

=end comment

=cut
```

When I use `Getotp::Long`, I prefer to use a single hash variable (like `%opt`) instead of several scalar variables.  I find it cleaner.

Indentation is excellent, except for  the `ext` line in the `GetOptions` call.  This is a bit more consistent:

```
GetOptions(
    'replace=s' => \$replace_char,
    'ext=s' => \$extension,
    'help' => \$help
) or die "Error in command line arguments\n";
```

I also changed the single quotes to double quotes in the `die` statement because it prints a literal `\n` instead of the intended newline character.  I ran your code through [perlcritic](https://metacpan.org/dist/Perl-Critic/view/bin/perlcritic) to find that one; sometimes it does find bugs in your code.

I prefer to explicitly declare all functions that are imported from modules:

```
use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptions);
use File::Find   qw(find);
```

This makes it clear where the functions are from, and it can limit adding lots of functions into the namespace if a module exports many functions by default.

I prefer to have one statement per line:

```
use version;
our $VERSION = qv('1.0.0');
```

Consider the [File::Spec](https://perldoc.perl.org/File::Spec) module instead of your `get_file_name` sub.

Comment: [That's gold, Jerry. Gold.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B359hCC3HQU&t=1s&ab_channel=Clips)